# How to write an avro file with Spark?

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, avro, spark-avro

I've an Array[Byte] that represents an avro schema. I'm trying to write it to Hdfs as avro file with spark. This is the code:

```
 val values = messages.map(row => (null,AvroUtils.decode(row._2,topic)))
    .saveAsHadoopFile(
      outputPath,
      classOf[org.apache.hadoop.io.NullWritable],
      classOf[CrashPacket],
      classOf[AvroOutputFormat[SpecificRecordBase]]
    )
```

row._2 is Array[Byte]

I'm getting this error: `org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 4 in stage 1.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 4.3 in stage 1.0 (TID 98, bdac1nodec06.servizi.gr-u.it): java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.io.StringReader.<init>(StringReader.java:50)
    at org.apache.avro.Schema$Parser.parse(Schema.java:958)
    at org.apache.avro.Schema.parse(Schema.java:1010)
    at org.apache.avro.mapred.AvroJob.getOutputSchema(AvroJob.java:143)
    at org.apache.avro.mapred.AvroOutputFormat.getRecordWriter(AvroOutputFormat.java:153)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkHadoopWriter.open(SparkHadoopWriter.scala:91)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$13.apply(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1068)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$13.apply(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1059)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:61)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:64)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:203)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)`

Answer (score 1):

Consider, that there is an avro class `StringPair` with constructor `StringPair(String a, String b)`. Then the code that writes records to avro files could look like this:

```
import com.test.{StringPair}
import org.apache.avro.Schema
import org.apache.avro.mapred.{AvroValue, AvroKey}
import org.apache.avro.mapreduce.{AvroKeyValueOutputFormat, AvroJob}
import org.apache.spark.{SparkConf, SparkContext}
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job

object TestWriteAvro {
  def main (args: Array[String]){
    val sparkConf = new SparkConf()
    val sc = new SparkContext(sparkConf)
    val job = new Job(sc.hadoopConfiguration)

    AvroJob.setOutputKeySchema(job, Schema.create(Schema.Type.STRING))
    AvroJob.setOutputValueSchema(job, StringPair.getClassSchema)
    val myRdd = sc
      .parallelize(List("1,2", "3,4"))
      .map(x => (x.split(",")(0), x.split(",")(1)))
      .map {case (x, y) => (new AvroKey[String](x), new AvroValue[StringPair](new StringPair(x, y)))}

    myRdd.saveAsNewAPIHadoopFile(args(0), classOf[AvroKey[_]], classOf[AvroValue[_]], classOf[AvroKeyValueOutputFormat[_, _]], job.getConfiguration)

    sc.stop()
  }
}
```